# focusing on next input (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I've got four inputs that each take one number. What I want to do is set the focus automatically to the next input once the number has been set. They all have the class "inputs".

This didn't quite work:

```
$(".inputs").keydown(function () {

            $(this).next().focus();
        });
```

Comment: See this post


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232379/setting-the-focus-to-the-next-input-in-jquery

Comment: See [updated post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10539258/297641) for some new features.. more like `autotab`  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qygB2/4/)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I would suggest setting maxlength as 1 to each textbox and switch to next one once the `val.length` and the `maxlength` is same.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qygB2/2/)

```
$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Spent some time for the following (not fully tested, but basic tests worked fine)

```
   1. Allowing just numeric chars  
   2. Allow some control like del, backspace, e.t.c
   3. Backspace on empty textbox will move to prev textbox
   4. charLimit var to dynamically decide how many char you want to restrict.
```

**Code:**

```
$(function() {
    var charLimit = 1;
    $(".inputs").keydown(function(e) {

        var keys = [8, 9, /*16, 17, 18,*/ 19, 20, 27, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 46, 144, 145];

        if (e.which == 8 && this.value.length == 0) {
            $(this).prev('.inputs').focus();
        } else if ($.inArray(e.which, keys) >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (this.value.length >= charLimit) {
            $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
            return false;
        } else if (e.shiftKey || e.which <= 48 || e.which >= 58) {
            return false;
        }
    }).keyup (function () {
        if (this.value.length >= charLimit) {
            $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qygB2/4/)

Comment: Wow this is excellent. I'll combine that with click(), so it resets the value when the user selects an already filled textbox. Right now if the user selects a filled input and types a number it focuses on the not the next input but the one after it (assuming all textboxes are filled). In an ideal scenario I guess it would not require deleting the number before typing a new one (it would replace it automatically). I can see how this would become problematic to implement with more than 1 char limit though. Just my thoughts. click() will do the trick for me anyway :)

Comment: @domino Nice find, but just couldn't let go of that.. so here the fix >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/qygB2/5/ << . Please try and let me know.

Comment: if there are input type disabled what should i modify to make it working ?

Comment: Is it accepting the zero value? I tried but it's not accepting. Also, what is the meaning of the keys number?

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    focusable: function (el, index, selector) {
        return $(el).is('a, button, :input,[tabindex]');
    }
});
$(document).on('keypress', 'input,select', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get all focusable elements on the page
        var $canfocus = $(':focusable');
        var index = $canfocus.index(document.activeElement) + 1;
        if (index >= $canfocus.length) index = 0;
        $canfocus.eq(index).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Best solution I have seen for mimicking a <tab> keypress. For some reason the `$(':focusable')` selector worked for me without extending jQuery, so the only code I needed was the four lines following the `//Get all ...` comment.

Answer (score 5):

That will just get the next element, whatever it is. You probably want:

```
$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
  $(this).next(".inputs").focus();
});
```

Also, key up not keydown or it will change too soon.

Comment: Ah yes. Could the keyup function ignore the delete/backspace key somehow?

Comment: Actually there's a bunch of other keys such as the tab key etc that would cause problems. I guess the easiest way would be to filter numbers only?

Comment: @domino That would be a different question.

Comment: if you delete or backspace the number then also it's going to next input

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I use for making enter key to behave as tab, i.e, focus to next element when pressing the Enter key or focusing previous element when pressing shift+Enter.

1) Essentially:

```
tabables = $("*[tabindex != '-1']:visible");
var index = tabables.index(element);
tabables.eq(index + 1).focus();
```

2) Here you are a "class" that encapsulates the behaviour, having in mind fordward and backwards and valid focusable elements.

I hope it helps and if some code suits your needs, feel free to adapt to your needs :)

```
EnterAsTab = function () {
    this.ENTER_KEY = 13;
};

EnterAsTab.prototype.init = function () {
    this.listenOnEnterKey();
};

EnterAsTab.prototype.listenOnEnterKey = function () {

    var me = this;
    $('form input').on('keypress', function (event) {

            if (event.which === me.ENTER_KEY) {

                if (!event.shiftKey)
                    me.findNextFocusableElement(this);
                else
                    me.findPreviousFocusableElement(this);

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    );
};

EnterAsTab.prototype.findNextFocusableElement = function (element) {
    this.findFocusableElement(element, this.increaseIndex);
};

EnterAsTab.prototype.findPreviousFocusableElement = function (element) {
    this.findFocusableElement(element, this.decreaseIndex);
};

EnterAsTab.prototype.findFocusableElement = function (element, callable) {

    var tabables = $("*[tabindex != '-1']:visible");
    var index = tabables.index(element);
    var counter = 1;
    var nextElement = undefined;

    try {

        while (true) {

            if ((nextElement = tabables.eq(index + counter)).length === 0) {
                break;
            }

            if (this.isFocusableElement(nextElement)) {

                var newIndex = callable.call(this, index, counter);
                tabables.eq(newIndex).focus();

                break;
            } else {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

};

EnterAsTab.prototype.increaseIndex = function (index, counter) {
    return (index + counter);
};

EnterAsTab.prototype.decreaseIndex = function (index, counter) {
    return index - counter;
};

EnterAsTab.prototype.isFocusableElement = function (element) {

    return ['SELECT', 'TEXTAREA'].indexOf(element.prop('tagName')) > -1 ||
        element.is(':text') ||
        element.is(':checkbox') ||
        element.is(':radio');
};

var enterAsTab = new EnterAsTab();
enterAsTab.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching and developing I end up in a crossbrowser snippet which makes it possible to focus the next input field with same class depending on maxlength (tested with 1 character) also with the ability to focus back via backspace button:

Javascript (jquery):

```
var codeCharInput = 'input.code-char';
$(codeCharInput+':first').focus();
$(codeCharInput).keyup(function(e) {
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46)) {
    $(this).prev(codeCharInput).focus().val($(this).prev().val());
  } else {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next(codeCharInput).focus();
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="chars[]" maxlength="1" class="code-char" />
<input type="text" name="chars[]" maxlength="1" class="code-char" />
<input type="text" name="chars[]" maxlength="1" class="code-char" />
<input type="text" name="chars[]" maxlength="1" class="code-char" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to look at the next input but you have say separators in the way like this

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD" name="dobday" id="dobday">
<div class="separator">/</div>
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM" name="dobmonth" id="dobmonth">
<div class="separator">/</div>
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" name="dobyear" id="dobyear">
```

You will need to use this code to get all the next items and settle on the first input found:

```
$('input#dobday,input#dobmonth,input#dobyear').on('input', function(e) {
    if (jQuery(this).val().length >= parseInt(jQuery(this).attr("maxlength"), 10)) {
            if (jQuery(this).attr('id') === 'dobyear') {
                jQuery(this).blur();
            } else {
                jQuery(this).nextAll('input:first').focus();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly
It also checks if the middle inputs are filled

```
$(".inputs").keyup( function () {

    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    var n=$(this).next('.inputs');
    n.focus();
   if(n.val().length==n.prop('maxlength')) n.next('.inputs').focus(); 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` e.g.

```
$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
    $(this).next().focus();
});​
```

See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/qygB2/

Comment: if you delete or backspace the number then also it's going to next input

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest jQuery version, I strongly recommend you to use the `on` method. If you go to the jQuery source code, you'll notice that all the other event methods now redirect to this method, so why don't use it directly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.inputs').on('keyup', function(){
            $(this).next().focus();
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will keep focus on the text box, after using next without naming the class or id.

```
 $(this).hide();        
 $(this).next().show();
 $('input[type=text]').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Vega's answer

```
inputs.keydown(function(e) {
    var keys = [8, 9, /*16, 17, 18,*/ 19, 20, 27, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 46, 144, 145];

    $(this).val('');

    if (e.which == 8 && this.value.length == 0) {
        $(this).prev(inputs).focus();
    } else if ($.inArray(e.which, keys) >= 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (this.value.length > charLimit) {
        $(this).next(inputs).focus();
        return false;
    } else if (e.shiftKey || e.which <= 48 || e.which >= 58) {
        return false;
    }
}).keyup (function () {
    if (this.value.length >= charLimit && $(this).next(inputs).attr('type') === 'text') {
        $(this).next(inputs).focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

If a user clicks on an input that already has a value it will override it, instead of going to the next input, it will also only focus on text inputs. I had a situation where I had a submit input next to the text inputs and if using backspace could accidentally redirect the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that complete your all needs.

```
$(".input").keyup(function(e) {

if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46){ 
    //backspace / Delete
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).prevAll('input:first').focus();
}
else
{ 
    var spcl_arr = ["~","!","@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "+","-", "=", "." ,"/"];
   if(e.which == 13){ // Enter Kay
      return false;
   }
  else if(jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), spcl_arr) !== -1 ){ 
         $(this).val('');
         $(this).focus();
        return false;
   }else{ 
       var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) { 
             if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
                 $(this).next('.input').focus();
             }
        }else{
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

});