# Focus on next input field inside table with enter key press

Tags: jquery

I need to move in to the next input field inside a table with many rows using enter key press. I try this :

```
$(function() {

    $('input').keyup(function (e) {
       if (e.which == 13) {
       $(this).find().next('input').focus();
       }
     });

});
```

Why dont work ? :(

**HTML**

```
<table class="half">
  <tr>
  <td>Nome :</td>
  <td><input name="ragsoc" type="text" id="ragsoc" value=""/></td>
  <td>Mnemo:</td>
  <td><input name="mnemo" type="text" id="mnemo" value=""/></td>
  <td>Partita IVA :</td>
  <td><input name="piva" type="text" id="piva" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Nome :</td>
  <td><input name="ragsoc" type="text" id="ragsoc" value=""/></td>
  <td>Mnemo:</td>
  <td><input name="mnemo" type="text" id="mnemo" value=""/></td>
  <td>Partita IVA :</td>
  <td><input name="piva" type="text" id="piva" value=""/></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

This code work fine but only in the first row of table :

```
$('input').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
    $(this).closest('td').nextAll().eq(1).find('input').focus()
    }
 });
```

What is wrong or missing ?

Comment: We need to see your html.

Comment: try `$(this).nextAll('.inputs:first').focus()`

Comment: Without seeing the html, any answer is a best a guess.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming `.inputs` is a sibling of your current element. `.find()` searches in descendants of current element(this)

```
 $('.inputs').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
       $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
    }
 });
```

You need to use [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [**.nextAll()**](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)

```
 $('.inputs').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        $(this).closest('td').nextAll().eq(1).find('.inputs').focus();

        //OR
        //$(this).closest('td').next().next().find('.inputs').focus()
    }
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HF432/1/)

As OP has updated question. Use

```
 $('.inputs').keydown(function (e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
         var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
         $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
     }
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HF432/2/), As note I have used `class="inputs"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it didn't work, because you are not using any parameter for the `find()` method.

And try this simly:

```
$('#txt').keydown(function (e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
     $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
   }
});
```

Or this:

```
$('#txt').keydown(function (e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
     $(this).find('.inputs').focus();
   }
});
```

These would work!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.inputs').keydown(function (e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
     $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
 }
});
```

Comment: just to be clear `$(this).next('.inputs')` won't find the next input, it will fetch the next sibling element (whatever it is) and return it only if it has class `inputs`

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(event.target);
    var index = parseFloat($this.attr('data-index'));
    $('[data-index="' + (index + 1).toString() + '"]').focus();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxZSU/1/

Font:

[focusing on next input (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539113/focusing-on-next-input-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in angular, I have added jQuery as well. You get the idea. It is same for all javascript.

I have table with dynamic row. field-focus class with each td input.

```
<tr>
  <td>
<textarea name="labResultAlpha" cols="25" rows="1" class="field-focus" (keydown)="keyPressFunction($event)"></textarea>   
  </td>
</tr>
```

TypeScript/Javascript
METHOD 1

```
enterPressFunction(e) {
    const focus = $(document.activeElement); //get your active elememt ie select input
    let inputView;
    if (e.which === 13) {
      inputView = focus.closest('tbody').next().find(".field-focus"); // go to tbody and search for next class name .field-focus
    }
    inputView.show().focus(); //focus and show next input in table
  }
```

If this didt work try second one.
METHOD 2

```
keyPressFunction(e) {    
    const focus = $(document.activeElement); //get current element
    if (e.which === 13) { //if entered is clicked
      focus.closest('tr').next('tr').find('.field-focus').focus(); //get current row,go to next row of current row and find field-focus class, focus on input
    }

  }
```