# How do you tab through text in html text input?

Tags: html, text, input, tabs

So I need a way of being able to tab to the next line in an html text input without it skipping to the next html input, is this possible?

Comment: Hello. You might want to edit your question because it's not clear. Do you want, as a User to use tabs in the text input or do you want to create an input text area where it is possible to tab ? Both questions have different answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Jquery:

1. [Activating next input field in form on enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610357/activating-next-input-field-in-form-on-enter)
2. [Focus on next input field inside table with enter key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240316/focus-on-next-input-field-inside-table-with-enter-key-press)
3. [focusNextInputField With jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/b8dFK/)

Easiest one is:

```
    $("input").change(function() {  
      var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');  
      inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).focus();  
    });
```

If these solutions doesn't help then provide your code, so that it will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are trying to MAKE a textarea field where users can tab, you **don't** need jQuery.
See this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2wAzx/13/

```
function enableTab(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed

            // get caret position/selection
            var val = this.value,
                start = this.selectionStart,
                end = this.selectionEnd;

            // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
            this.value = val.substring(0, start) + '\t' + val.substring(end);

            // put caret at right position again
            this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

            // prevent the focus lose
            return false;

        }
    };
}

// Enable the tab character onkeypress (onkeydown) inside textarea...
// ... for a textarea that has an `id="my-textarea"`
enableTab('my-textarea');
```

Also, if that is your question, i'd recommend marking it as a duplicate since it has been asked more than once on SO...