# Automatically move to next line after input detected with a possible timer

Tags: javascript, forms, timer

After a bit of research I stumbled onto [this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881754/how-to-move-next-input-tab-after-fill-4-characters) It was a nice example but not exactly what I was looking for.

What I'm trying to do is this, I have a barcode scanner connected to my PC, and i want to be able to scan something into a form field and it automatically move to the next line regardless of how many numbers have been scanned (UPC-A or UPC-E) from the barcode.

And I felt the best way to do that is after the field is been filed with code/numbers it waits 1 second and moves to the next line. Or if someone  has another suggestion on moving to the next line, I'm open to suggestions, i just want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jQuery, and assuming that your barcode scanner simulates a keyboard (and therefore sends keyboard events):

```
var timer;
$('input').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    var input = $(this);
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
       input.next('input').focus();
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r595Y/

Comment: What if I want the Inputs to be in rows? not just on 1 single line. for example when I try to place a <br> inbetween each input it stops working.

Comment: You'd need to adjust the selector for the next input as following: `input.nextAll('input:first')` (see http://jsfiddle.net/r595Y/3/).