# jQuery Plugin to enter characters separately (for example for phone token verification)

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery Plugin where you can enter characters separately and after you entered a character it jumps to the next character field. This kind of input is often used in connection with phone number verfication tokens. I hope you know what I mean. I also added an image of how stripe (https://stripe.com) implemented this function. Do you know any?
Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: Could you not use the .blur() and then give focus to the next field, or something like that?

Comment: thanks, I just thougt there would already be some plugins (maybe although with some design) out there

Comment: google gave me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539113/focusing-on-next-input-jquery

Comment: This may help too. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-auto-focus-on-next-text-input-textbox

Just need to work out the logic on moving to the next field. May want to consider some validation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example, a plugin is not needed: https://jsfiddle.net/yomtym8L/

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").on("keypress", function() {
        $(this).next().focus();
    })
})
```

On key press of one input, focus its next sibling

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```