# move cursor automatically from on numeric input field to next field

Tags: javascript

I have two html input[type=number] fields. Each field contain 2 digit numeric velue. After entering 2 digit, I want to move the cursor to the next field automatically. How can I do this with Jquery or javaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [focusing on next input (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539113/focusing-on-next-input-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can check length of input of first textbox inside keyup event, then if length equals 2, focus on second input box as.

```
document.getElementById("id_of_second_textbox").focus();
```